# The best database server for java?

Tags: java

For languages like C#, VB.NET, C++ we have the best database server as SQL Server, I know we can program with SQL server or any other ODBC supported database servers in java but I'm not sure what is the best for java? Could you please give me some names?

Thank you very much!

Comment: oh, a question for "the best [insert tool/manufacturer here]". You should consider the database features. Java can link to nearly every database in some form or another

Comment: You can use any database that has a JDBC driver. Whether it is the 'best' depends on the features you need as provided by the DB and JDBC driver. Everything else is just preference and 'use what you know'.

Comment: With Java you can also consider one of the 150+ NoSQL databases http://nosql-database.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can afford it, it's Oracle.  If not use MySQL, the most popular Db. They are all Oracle products, just like Java.

Comment: -1 Unsubstantiated claims are not an actual answer

Comment: Mark, as a developer for a competing database you owe it to the OP to disclose that.  I was only commenting from experience with a number of databases and JDBC ranging from Access to Oracle.  If the question had been about PHP, I would not have recommended Oracle as PDO has incomplete support (Blobs and Clobs) and getting Symfony 1.2 and Doctrine to use it was a chore.

Comment: JDBC is very much vendor agnostic (from all languages I know it solves database independence the best). If a database has a JDBC driver it - almost - doesn't matter which one you use. The JDBC standard and drivers predate ownership of Java by Oracle by about 15 years; your claim that Oracle is the best for Java because Java is also owned by Oracle is unsubstantiated. If you had quoted sources that show that Oracle JDBC implements most optional features and it is most compliant to the spec, or you posted a comparison between JDBC implementations, I'd agree (or at least wouldn't have downvoted)